# Iterator Implementation for generic binary search tree

Tags: java, generics, iterator, binary-search-tree

I'm slightly confused as to how I would implement an iterator for this particular generic bst I'm doing the implementation for. Here's some of the code:

```
public class BinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractSet<E> {
protected Entry<E> root;
protected int size;
public BinSearchTree() {
    root = null;
    size = 0;
}
public BinSearchTree(BinSearchTree<E> otherTree) {

    LinkedList<Entry <E>> elements= new LinkedList<Entry<E>>();
    elements.add(otherTree.root);
    while(!elements.isEmpty()){
        BinSearchTree.add(elements.remove());
    }

}
```

Here's roughly what I have to implement

```
 protected class TreeIterator implements Iterator<E> {



    /**
     * Positions this TreeIterator to the smallest
     * element, according to the Comparable interface,
     * in the BST object.  The worstTime(n) is O(n)
     * and averageTime(n) is O(log n).
     */
    protected TreeIterator() {

    }

    /**
     * Determines if there are still some elements,
     * in the BST object this TreeIterator object is
     * iterating over, that have not been accessed by
     * this TreeIterator object.
     *
     * @return true - if there are still some elements
     *         that have not been accessed by this
     *         TreeIterator object; otherwise, return
     *         false.
     */ 
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Returns the element in the Entry this
     * TreeIterator object was positioned at 
     * before this call, and advances this 
     * TreeIterator object.  The worstTime(n) is O(n)
     * and averageTime(n) is constant.
     *
     * @return the element this TreeIterator object
     *         was positioned at before this call.
     *
     * @throws NoSuchElementException - if this 
     *         TreeIterator object was not positioned
     *         at an Entry before this call.
     */
    public E next() {
        return null;   

    }

    /**
     * Removes the element returned by the most recent
     * call to this TreeIterator object’s next() method.
     * The worstTime(n) is O(n) and averageTime(n) is
     * constant.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException - if this 
     *         TreeIterator’s next() method was not
     *         called before this call, or if this 
     *         TreeIterator’s remove() method was called
     *         between the call to the next() method and
     *         this call.
     */ 
    public void remove() {


    }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not code writing service.

Comment: please show what did you try and what problem did you face. For BST traversal there is a well known algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: I don't understand this line: `BinSearchTree.add(elements.remove())` You're calling a static method `add`?